# In Python, how do you loop and write to a file for only a specific number of times?

Tags: python

I have a dict. There are about 10,000 key:value pairs in this dict.

I want to write these pairs(just as strings) 1-100 to a file, then pairs 101-200 to a second file, then 201-300 to a third file etc.

How would one do that in python?

Answer (score 1):

The iteration methods is based on [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

```
c = 0
f = open('%d.txt'%(c),'w')
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print>>f,"%s:%s"%(str(key),str(value))
    c += 1
    if c % 100 == 0:
        f.close()
        f = open('%d.txt'%(c/100),'w')
f.close()
```

Comment: Note that this works for Python2. If in Python3, you'll need to use `d.items()` to iterate over the key-value pairs of the dictionary (in addition to using parentheses for the `print` function).